# Why is not Owl carousel dots showing?

Tags: javascript

`Owl Carousel` is running well **but dots are not showing in `prestashop 1.6` module**. So, how can I show dots ? Please any help.

I am using

/**
owl.carousel.min.css

- Owl Carousel v2.2.0
- Copyright 2013-2016 David Deutsch
- Licensed under MIT
  */

/**
owl.carousel.js

- Owl Carousel v2.2.0
- Copyright 2013-2016 David Deutsch
- Owl carousel
- @version 2.1.6

Results

[image]

My code is in tpl file in module of prestashop 1.6 :

```
      <div class="panel">  
           <h1 class="panel_title">All Products .............. ( {$id_shop} )</h1>   
           <div class="store_wise_products">
               <div class="owl-carousel store_wise_slider" style="background:#eee; padding:2px;">
                  {foreach from=$shopImgSql_results key=k item=shopImg}   
                      <div class="item"> 
                           <img  class="img-responsive"  src="{$dir_assets}uploadslider/{$shopImg.shop_img_name}-{$shopImg.id}-{$shopImg.img_extension}"> 
                      </div> 
                  {/foreach} 
              </div>
         </div> 
      </div>  





    <script>  
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            var owl = $('.store_wise_slider'); 
            owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            autoplay:true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            lazyLoad: true, 
            margin: 10,
            items: 1, 
            navText: [ '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>' ],  
            responsive: {
              0: {
                 items:1
                }, 
             } 
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your css may be overrrided by libraries which you are using inspect the dots and check if it is display none or hidden.

Comment: I think you should make a fiddle then, we will able to debug easily.